# Is it possible to use a conditional directive without a switch type setup in angular2

Tags: angular

I'm currently doing something like

```
<div *ngFor="let directive in listOfDirectives">
    <directive-one *ngIf="directive == 'directive-one'"></directive-one>
    <directive-two *ngIf="directive == 'directive-two'"></directive-two>
    ...
</div>
```

What I'd like to do is this however it doesn't work

```
<{{directive}} *ngFor="let directive = listofDirectives"></{{directive}}>
```

So is there a way to do this? For styling purposes i really need the  to not be wrapped with a div

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
<{{directive}} *ngFor="let directive = listofDirectives"></{{directive}}>
```

is not supported.

Only HTML that is statically added to a template is matched against selectors of components and directives.

You can add dynamic components using `ViewContainerRef.createComponent` like explained for example in [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)